# strange type conversion with one particular function

Tags: c++, class

I'm relatively new to object oriented code so I may be missing something simple. The code below is mostly skeleton code from function prototypes in another file. The problem is with the Light::setMessage() function. As is, I'm getting this error when I compile.

```
metaphase.cpp:25:27: error: cannot convert ‘Light::checkMessageValid’ from type ‘bool (Light::)()’ to type ‘bool’
```

Since I'm new to classes, it wouldn't suprise me if I'm doing something wrong, but if I remove the if(checkMessageValid) and leave the others it compiles. I know there is nothing in these functions but I don't see why the compiler isn't treating them exactly the same.

```
#include "lighting.hpp"

bool Light::checkMessageValid( void )
{
    return false;
}

bool Light::_setChannel( unsigned int ch )
{
    return false;
}

bool Light::_setCommand( unsigned int co )
{
    return false;
}

bool Light::_setData( unsigned int d )
{
    return false;
}

bool Light::setMessage( unsigned int ch, unsigned int co, unsigned int d )
{
    if( checkMessageValid )
    {
        if( !_setChannel( ch ) )
            return false;
        if( !_setCommand( co ) )
            return false;
        if( !_setData( d ) )
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `checkMessageValid` is a function, not a variable. Functions have to get called, `checkMessageValid()`.

The error basically states that `checkMessageValid` (of type `bool (Light::)()`) can't be converted into a `bool`. An `if` statement requires a `bool` (to compare), and so the compiler tries to convert the function type into a `bool`, but fails, because there is no such conversion.

Comment: note that `chessMessageValid` does not actually have type `bool (Light::)()`  , so this is a bogus error message. Member functions are not analogous to free functions in this regard; for example to form a pointer to one, the `&` operator is required.  The compiler could do a better job of making its error messages in this case.

Comment: @M.M what type does it have them? Because I thought that member functions had that type signature.